# When $\frac{a^2+b^2}{a-b}$ is a divisor of 2015?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it possibly to prove this problem?
Yes!
Prime factorisation of 2015 and then?

Find all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ for which $\frac{a^2+b^2}{a-b}$ is an integer and divides 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It follows that $a^2+b^2$ is a divisor of $2015$.

Which divisors of $2015$ can be written as a sum of two squares?

Recall that a number is a sum of two squares iff its prime factors of the form $4k+3$ appear with even exponent.

Since $2015 = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 31$,  $a^2+b^2$ can only be composed of $5$ and $13$, and so $a^2+b^2$ can only be $1$, $5$, $13$, $65$. Only $5$ and $13$ work and give $a=2$, $b=1$, and $a=3$, $b=2$. (You can swap $a$ and $b$ as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Next, I ran a quick program to return the integers that divide 2015. The integers are:

> [1, 2015, 65, 155, 5, 403, 13, 31] = (*)
>
> This pool is composed of three prime numbers: 5,13,31.

So, for all cases where `your_formula(a,b)` is equal to the above, we have a true statement. I would start by looking at cases where `(a^2)+(b^2) = 5(a-b)`. "At what point do my choices for `a` and `b` (by squaring and adding them) even equal 5?" The answer is when:

`b(b+5) = a(5-a)` --Found with algebra, call this `(**)`

Do two positive numbers exist that not only makes the above statement true, but also makes `b/a = 1` true? The answer is no. And this is true for all primes.

This same approach can be done with all of the integers that are in `(*)`, and should be done by just replacing the 5 in `(**)` with some other value in `(*)`.

But first, let us see if we can solve for a number that is a multiple of 5. We can solve for ten (10 = 5*2, so we are looking for b and a such that b/a = 2, which works for b=10 and a = 5). So, let us look for b/a = 13. This implies that b = 13*a.

Which further implies that `(13a)(13a+5) = (a)(5-a)`, from `(**)`. Is this statement True or False? This can be done multiple times until all are proven.

Comment: You may find a way to incorporate that $(a-b)$ also divides $2b^2$, as $a^2+b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) + 2b^2$